# How much would a java code signature from a Certification Authority cost?

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, jnlp

In January 2014, with the new java update 7u51, the signature of applets and web start application will be required.
Considering that a workaround with self signed signatures wouldn´t fit my needs, I would like to know how much it would cost to buy it from a Certification Authority.
Thanks :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cost of an off-site-resource

Answer (score 1):

In https://author.tucows.com/ they offer 3-year code signing certificates for $195. That was the best deal I could find.

Comment: For me this might be better http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-comparison.html?ids=16

Comment: Be careful. They're selling 1-year cetificate for $99. 2-year for $177.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_rules.html